# Amplify config file production

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, github, encryption, aws-amplify

I use Angular and Amplify Auth. I have a separate CodePipeline in AWS and I use GitHub. My Question is how I can encrypt the config file for production.

config file:

```
const awsmobile = {
  aws_project_region: "eu-central-X",
  aws_cognito_identity_pool_id:
    "eu-central-1:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  aws_cognito_region: "eu-central-X",
  aws_user_pools_id: "eu-central-X_XXXXXXXXX",
  aws_user_pools_web_client_id: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  oauth: {}
};
```

reference in *main.ts*

```
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import awsmobile from "./aws-exports";
Amplify.configure(awsmobile);
```

I was thinking about using [crypto.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) - or a Github secret. But maybe there is a better solution. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Actually - they are all parameters, none of them are secret,  so you don't need to encrypt them.

Even if you would encrypt the parameters, you would need to decrypt them before use on the client side. There's no point in that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the credentials are already frontend encrypted. There is no need to use crypto.js.